# Create directory junction on remote machine

Tags: command-line-interface, remote-access, mount, junction, mklink

I need to create a directory junction (hard symbolic link) between two directories on a remote machine. The directories are both on the remote machine. I tried doing it by mounting the folder, but I get an error;

```
c:\>net use g: \\server-name\Share
c:\>g:
g:\>mklink /J LinkName SourceFolder
Local NTFS volumes are required to complete the operation.
```

What is the easiest way to accomplish this? I could fall back to using PowerShell remoting but that means I need to spend ages configuring authentication.